# Why Am I Getting Authorization Failed for Pinterest App?

Tags: pinterest

I just ran the command below on my newly created app and get Authorization Failed message. I ran the Token Debugger and the access token is good. How do I fix this?

```
https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/pins/?access_token=<ACCESS-TOKEN>&fields=id,creator,note&limit=1
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "status": "failure", 
  "code": 3, 
  "data": null, 
  "message": "Authorization failed.", 
  "endpoint_name": "get_own_pins"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your **access token** with the **api.pinterest.com** url

```
https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/pins/?
    access_token=<YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN>
    &fields=id,note
    &limit=1
```

Replace `<YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN>` with your pinterest access token

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, that I did use my access token. I just used that to mask it when asking the question.